# XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, fontspec, unicode and normalization

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode

I am troubled by the way LuaTeX and XeLaTeX normalize unicode composed character. I mean NFC / NFD.

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}


ᾳ GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA (U+03B1) + COMBINING GREEK YPOGEGRAMMENI (U+0345)

ᾳ GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH YPOGEGRAMMENI (U+1FB3)

\end{document}
```

With LuaLaTeX I obtain:
[image: Example compiled with LuaLaTeX]

As you can see, Lua does not normalize unicode character, and as Linux Libertine has a bug (http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/bugs/266/), I have a bad character.

With XeLaTeX, I obtain[image: Example compiled with XeLaTeX]

As you can see, the Unicode is normalized.

My three questions are :

1. Why XeLaTeX has normalized (in NFC), despite I have not used `\XeTeXinputnormalization`
2. Did this feature change from the past. Because my previous, with TeXLive 2012 send be a bad result (see the articles I wrote at this time http://geekographie.maieul.net/Normalisation-des-caracteres)
3. Does LuaTeX has option like there is `\XeTeXinputnormalization` in XeTeX?

Comment: Imho HarfBuzz (used by xetex since version XY) does an additional normalization, so the value of `\XeTeXinputnormalization` doesn't matter much.

Comment: The luatex manual (`texdoc lua`) section 2.3 says you can do unicode normalisation in the file reader callback, but doesn't give an example. I have a feeling I've seem one somewhere, either an answer here, or the context sources or....

Comment: yes, I have looked for NFD/NFD and found nothing...

Comment: indeed, harfbuzz normalize in some condition http://cgit.freedesktop.org/harfbuzz/tree/src/hb-ot-shape-normalize.cc#n32 and xetex use it since version 1.99 and XeTeX use it. see http://www.khaledhosny.org/node/198

Comment: so, I have to look for luatex.

Comment: ConTeXt does normalisation in Lua (but doesn’t call it that); I also wrote code for that independently, as part of my Google Summer of Code project a long time ago (https://code.google.com/p/google-summer-of-code-2008-tex/downloads/list), but it’s never been used anywhere that I know of.

Comment: hum, it look like nice, but I am not able to use it (maybe because I dont know not a lot about LuaTeX;-)

Comment: I thinkg it will be nice to have such feature. Because if we present LuaTeX as the feature of TeX, some basic behavior for people who works with non-english character are needed. I didn't understand in the past why I had a problem....

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have time to take on yet another project right now, but others are welcome to use my code, of course.  It will probably – certainly – need an update to reflect the past 7 years of changes in LuaTeX.

Comment: yes. For my own case, i will prefer to normalize the input file in the first time, not in the fly. I have already my package. I was just to be sure.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer file `lua-utilities.lua` is missing in the archive, so test files can't run (function `uni_string_name` is needed in particular). is any chance you have this file somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the answer for first two questions, as I don't use XeTeX, but I want to provide option for the third question.

Thanks to [Arthur's code](https://code.google.com/p/google-summer-of-code-2008-tex/downloads/list) I was able to create basic package for unicode normalization in LuaLaTeX. The code needed only slight modifications to work with current LuaTeX. I will post only main Lua file here, full project is available on [Github as uninormalize](https://github.com/michal-h21/uninormalize).

Sample usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[nodes,buffer=false, debug]{uninormalize}
\begin{document}

Some tests:
\begin{itemize}
  \item combined letter ᾳ %GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA (U+03B1) + COMBINING GREEK YPOGEGRAMMENI (U+0345)
  \item normal letter ᾳ% GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH YPOGEGRAMMENI (U+1FB3)
\end{itemize}

Some more combined and normal letters: 
óóōōöö

Linux Libertine does support some combined chars: \parbox{4em}{příliš}
\end{document}
```

(note that correct version of this file is on Github, combined letters were transferred incorrectly in this example)

Main idea of the package is following: process the input, and when letter followed by combined marks is found, then it is replaced by normalized NFC form. Two methods are provided, my first approach was to use node processing callbacks to replace decomposed glyphs with normalized characters. This would have a advantage in that it would be possible to switch on and off the processing anywhere, using node attributes. The other possible feature could be checking if the current font contains normalized character and use original form if it doesn't. Unfortunately, in my tests it fails with some characters, notably composed `í` is in the nodes as `dotless i + ´`, instead of `i + ´`, which after the normalization doesn't produce the correct character, so  composed chars are used instead. But this produce output with bad placing of the accent. So this method needs either some correction, or it is totally wrong.

So the other method is to use `process_input_buffer` callback to normalize the input file as it is read from the disk. This method doesn't allow to use info from fonts, nor it allows to turning off in the middle of the line, but it is significantly easier to implement, the callback function may look like this:

```
function buffer_callback(line) 
  return NFC(line)
end
```

which is really nice finding after three days spent on node processing version.

For curiosity this is the Lua package:

```lua
local M = {}
dofile("unicode-names.lua")
dofile('unicode-normalization.lua')
local NFC = unicode.conformance.toNFC
local char = unicode.utf8.char
local gmatch = unicode.utf8.gmatch
local name = unicode.conformance.name
local byte = unicode.utf8.byte
local unidata = characters.data
local length = unicode.utf8.len

M.debug = false

-- for some reason variable number of arguments doesn't work
local function debug_msg(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
  if M.debug then
    local t = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}
    print("[uninormalize]", unpack(t))
  end
end

local function make_hash (t) 
  local y = {}
  for _,v in ipairs(t) do 
    y[v] = true
  end
  return y
end

local letter_categories = make_hash {"lu","ll","lt","lo","lm"}

local mark_categories = make_hash {"mn","mc","me"}

local function printchars(s)
    local t = {}
    for x in gmatch(s,".") do
        t[#t+1] = name(byte(x))
    end
    debug_msg("characters",table.concat(t,":"))
end

local categories = {}


local function get_category(charcode)
  local charcode = charcode or ""
  if categories[charcode] then
    return categories[charcode] 
  else
    local unidatacode = unidata[charcode] or {}
    local category = unidatacode.category
    categories[charcode] = category
    return category
  end
end

-- get glyph char and category
local function glyph_info(n)
  local char = n.char
  return char, get_category(char)
end

local function get_mark(n)
  if n.id == 37 then
    local character, cat = glyph_info(n)
    if mark_categories[cat] then
      return char(character)
    end
  end
  return false
end

local function make_glyphs(head, nextn,s, lang, font, subtype) 
  local g = function(a) 
    local new_n = node.new(37, subtype)
    new_n.lang = lang
    new_n.font = font
    new_n.char = byte(a)
    return new_n
  end
  if length(s) == 1 then
    return node.insert_before(head, nextn,g(s))
  else
    local t = {}
    local first = true
    for x in gmatch(s,".") do
      debug_msg("multi letter",x)
        head, newn = node.insert_before(head, nextn, g(x))
    end
    return head
  end
end

local function normalize_marks(head, n)
  local lang, font, subtype = n.lang, n.font, n.subtype
  local text = {}
  text[#text+1] = char(n.char)
  local head, nextn = node.remove(head, n)
  --local nextn = n.next
  local info = get_mark(nextn)
  while(info) do
    text[#text+1] = info
    head, nextn = node.remove(head,nextn)
    info = get_mark(nextn)
  end
  local s = NFC(table.concat(text))
  debug_msg("We've got mark: " .. s)
  local new_n = node.new(37, subtype)
  new_n.lang = lang
  new_n.font = font
  new_n.char = byte(s)
  --head, new_n = node.insert_before(head, nextn, new_n)
  -- head, new_n = node.insert_before(head, nextn, make_glyphs(s, lang, font, subtype))
  head, new_n = make_glyphs(head, nextn, s, lang, font, subtype)
  local t = {}
  for x in node.traverse_id(37,head) do
    t[#t+1] = char(x.char)
  end
  debug_msg("Variables ", table.concat(t,":"), table.concat(text,";"), char(byte(s)),length(s))
  return head, nextn
end

local function normalize_glyphs(head, n)
  --local charcode = n.char
  --local category = get_category(charcode)
  local charcode, category = glyph_info(n)
  if letter_categories[category] then 
    local nextn = n.next
    if nextn.id == 37 then
      --local nextchar = nextn.char
      --local nextcat = get_category(nextchar)
      local nextchar, nextcat = glyph_info(nextn)
      if mark_categories[nextcat] then
        return normalize_marks(head,n)
      end
    end
  end
  return head, n.next 
end


function M.nodes(head)
    local t = {}
    local text = false
  local n = head
    -- for n in node.traverse(head) do
  while n do
        if n.id == 37 then
      local charcode = n.char
            debug_msg("unicode name",name(charcode))
            debug_msg("character category",get_category(charcode))
            t[#t+1]= char(charcode)
            text = true
      head, n = normalize_glyphs(head, n)
        else
            if text then
                local s = table.concat(t)
                debug_msg("text chunk",s)
                --printchars(NFC(s))
                debug_msg("----------")
            end
            text = false
            t = {}
      n = n.next
        end
    end
    return head
end

--[[
-- These functions aren't needed when processing buffer. We can call NFC on the whole input line
local unibytes = {}

local function get_charcategory(s)
  local s = s or ""
  local b = unibytes[s] or byte(s) or 0
  unibytes[s] = b
  return get_category(b)
end

local function normalize_charmarks(t,i)
  local c = {t[i]}
  local i = i + 1
  local s = get_charcategory(t[i])
  while mark_categories[s] do
    c[#c+1] = t[i]
    i = i + 1
    s = get_charcategory(t[i])
  end
  return NFC(table.concat(c)), i
end

local function normalize_char(t,i)
  local ch = t[i]
  local c = get_charcategory(ch)
  if letter_categories[c] then
    local nextc = get_charcategory(t[i+1])
    if mark_categories[nextc] then
      return normalize_charmarks(t,i)
    end
  end
  return ch, i+1
end
-- ]]
function M.buffer(line)
  --[[
  local t = {}
  local new_t = {}
  -- we need to make table witl all uni chars on the line
  for x in gmatch(line,".") do
    t[#t+1] = x
  end
  local i = 1
  -- normalize next char
  local c, i = normalize_char(t, i)
  new_t[#new_t+1] = c
  while t[i] do
    c, i = normalize_char(t,i)
    -- local  c = t[i]
    -- i =  i + 1
    new_t[#new_t+1] = c
  end
  return table.concat(new_t)
  --]]
  return NFC(line)
end


return M
```

and now is the time for some pictures.

without normalization:

[image]

you can see that composed Greek char is wrong, other combinations are supported by Linux Libertine

with node normalization:

[image]

Greek letters are correct, but `í` in first `příliš` is wrong. this is the issue I was talking about.

and now the buffer normalization:

[image]

everything is alright now

Comment: that is very nice ! The bug of the í is very strang, as without normalization we have the good character. However, the second method (buffer normalization) is enough, isn't it ? Or do you have a good reason to prefer the first ? Will changing in the middle of the document? I think a  font without normalized form s is not good for a specific language ;-)

Comment: Thank a lot for this work. Do you think if could be published (after more test !) in CTAN?

Comment: @Maïeul the `í` bug probably depends on used font, when I switch to Latin Modern, it is correct. The first method would be nice because it has greater potential for context dependable modifications, but maybe it doesn't matter. maybe I like it more because I spent three days on it and in the end the better result is from one three line function :D

Comment: @Maïeul it should go to CTAN, I think, but I am really bad on releasing my packages on CTAN

Comment: Maybe it's like bug with "Ezra" Sil : there is also character conversion inside font. I know, for example, that Linux Libertine "Old Styles" digit are not in the normal unicode position, and Linux Libertine convert them.

Comment: I also think the "three day" is the true reason :)

Comment: @Maïeul yes, it is likely result of some opentype transformations inside the font

Comment: @Maïeul so does it work correctly for you?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see you have linked a github page. Yes, it's working. At least with the MWE, and I found no reason it could not work...

Comment: I tried out the code, it works fine for the example alpha with ypogegrammeni but not e.g. with U+0061 U+0301. I get no aacute (U+00E1) (with xetex it works).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is strange, [this example seems to work](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/bf5022f5f0b79037a0ee) (first á is decomposed, second is normalized)

Comment: @michal.h21: I found the reason: I had used ^^-notation and with ^^^^0061^^^^0301 ^^^^0041^^^^0301 it doesn't work. Looks as if the callback comes first.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer aha, try `nodes` package option. Default processing mode is to normalize input string, but it can't work with this notation. `nodes` use node callback instead, so it should work regardless of the method used to input text